# What is the MySQL driver class for saving Spring JPA entities?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, appdynamics

I have to create custom endpoint in App Dynamics for either java class/interface/annotation/abstract java class for MySQL, that would intercept mysql calls. Spring Boot is using JPA's CRUDRepository/JPARepository/Repository as an abstract layer to call vendor databases. Only class that implements them is SimpleRepository. JDBCTemplate is no longer used.

Now, when we have multiple datasources, I would like to pin the class/interface/abstract/annotation from MySQL side which is called internally by spring framework, specifically for saving/persisting/updating/deleting POJO entities. I would appreciate if somebody knows which class/interface is being called from MySQL side by spring repository interfaces mentioned above. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC driver class of MySql is

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

and thats what finally is called to execute SQL statements against a MySql database by JPA

Answer (score 0):

It is com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement with methods: Constructor and executeUpdate(). Thanks for answerin